# ユーザーのプロフィールページで「投稿がありません」メッセージの翻訳はありませんか?

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

コミュニティの「投稿がありません」メッセージの翻訳はありませんか?

メインサイトのコミュニティユーザーのプロフィールに行くと、次のような表示があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この文字列を翻訳する必要があると思います。

機械翻訳ですみません… 日本語はわかりませんが、お手伝いしたいのですが...

追伸 コミュニティのプロフィールは [ここ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A5%E3%83%8B%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3?tab=profile) です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

traducir で「このユーザーはまだ投稿していません。」と [翻訳を提案](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/15561) しておきました。
(実際に反映されるまでは数日程度かかると思うので、少し待ってみてください)

Comment: ありがとう！ ほんとうにありがとう。

Comment: この質問にマークを付けていただけますか [完了]?